# How to get XPATH of a defined element in DOM?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am doing some web scraping with Selenium and Python.
I want to get information from some website who doesn't want to give this data easily. To prevent giving data CSS selectors and IDs are variables. When I first load a page some element have id="u_ps_fetchstream_2_0_5" next time the same field has id="u_ps_fetchstream_4_3_2". IDs are also very sparsely used on this page. Retrieving some data through find_element_by_id is therefore not an option.

So I had this idea: I am looking for some data XX on the page. First I'd search for some text 'SAMPLE TEXT' which is in proximity of targeted data XX.
I'd do this with:

`elementXX = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'SAMPLE TEXT')]")`

Then I'd somehow get XPATH of elementXX and change it to target data XX near 'SAMPLE TEXT'. I know where is data XX relative to 'SAMPLE TEXT'.

My questions:

1. Is there a chance this will work? Is it feasible?
2. How can I get XPATH of elementXX?
3. What would you propose if answer to 1. is No?

Thanks.

Comment: Feasible with correct XPath axes. For example : `//*[contains(text(), 'SAMPLE TEXT')]/following::td`. Please provide a sample of the DOM if you need guidance to write the expression.

Comment: Before you go inside deeper xpath paths, please read something like the following link. I think it will help you to understand how you can make your own custom xpaths: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: You can get one example of DOM I'm working on at https://www.facebook.com/pg/Mizarstvo-Ma%C4%8Dek-180060362129055/about/?ref=page_internal . SAMPLE TEXT I'm looking for is FIND US and proximity fields I want to scrap are address, Messenger and phone fields below FIND US.